# Adding html in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am writing my first wordpress plugin. It's supposed to send a message on plugin page whenever user saves/edits pages. The problem is I can't quite get it to print the messages.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    /*
    Plugin Name: Monitor
    Plugin URI:
    Description: Test plugin monitoring user activities
    Author: 
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: 
    */


if (!function_exists('p_update')) {  
    function p_update( $post_id ) {
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $message = "Changed: " . $post_title . "Link: " . $post_url ;
        echo "<p>test1</p>"
    }
}

if (!function_exists('p_publish')) {
    function p_publish( $post_id ){
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $message = "abc";
        echo "<p>test2</p>"
    }
}

if (!function_exists('plugin_menu')) {
    function plugin_menu() {
        add_menu_page( 'Monitor', 'Monitor', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'plugin_options');
    }
}

if (!function_exists('plugin_options')) {
    function plugin_options() {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>test</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'plugin_menu' );
add_action('save_post', p_update);
add_action('publish_post', p_publish);

?>
```

The plugin_menu function displays html properly, but other functions can't do that. What am I doing wrong? I'm sure there is some easy way of doing that but no tutorial I've seen adresses this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean when user publish a post or save a post?

Comment: my first guess would be that you're trying to `echo` at a point in the code where there is nowhere to `echo` to.

Comment: you should probably review your previous questions on this site, your last 3/4 q's have not accepted answers. I can't speak for others but it discourages me from helping someone!

Comment: @MoshFeu I want to do both. But at this point the basic problem is that html doesn't appear on plugin page.

Comment: @WheatBeak That may be the reason. How can I point my functions to a plugin page?

Comment: Do you mean like plugin's `settings` page? If so, read this: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/

Comment: @MoshFeu Not exactly. I'm not trying to create options. I'm just trying to print a message using html on a plugin page. `p_update` and `p_publish` should do it when user does something to pages. However when I `echo` using those funcions nothing happens. What I want is a way to send to created plugin page html, so I can print message that way

Comment: I see.. May [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/displaying-errors-from-the-save_post-hook-in-wordpress/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `add_actions` like:

```
add_action('save_post', 'p_update');
add_action('publish_post', 'p_publish');
```

You should use '' in `add_action` function for function names